# bootstrap class in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, angular5

How to use bootstrap class like nav-component, data-toggle attribute in VS code for Angular 4&5 project component ?

it did not work in bootstrap v3. So I use bootstrap v 4.1.7. I have linked the source file in node_module of angular project. However, those classes and attributes are not applied in the page.

Can bootstrap 3 classes and attributes be used if we use bootstrap 4 source file in project ?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: look for ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 is a major rewrite of the entire project ([Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)). Thus, most of the attributes / CSS classes are changed in V4.

You need to learn bootstrap 4.

You can read migration guide from its [official page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)
Also you can check changed components from [this link](https://medium.com/@lukaszholeczek/migration-from-bootstrap-3-to-bootstrap-4-4ec63a1dd8b1)